# In PySpark StructStream,How to find the time difference between each row in a group and the previous row

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this data

```
+-----------------+----------------------+
|     customer    |       date_time      |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 12:10:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       B         | 2020-4-10 12:20:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 12:20:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       B         | 2020-4-10 12:25:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       B         | 2020-4-10 12:40:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 12:50:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 13:30:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 13:35:00   |
+-----------------+----------------------+
```

I want to group the customers in the data and then calculate the time difference between each row and the previous row in the group;
The additional column A is used to store the time difference between the current row of data in the customer group and the previous row of data

```
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|     customer    |       date_time      |     duration    |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 12:10:00   |       NaN       |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 12:20:00   |       10        |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 12:50:00   |       30        |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 13:30:00   |       40        |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       A         | 2020-4-10 13:35:00   |       5         |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       B         | 2020-4-10 12:20:00   |      NaN        |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       B         | 2020-4-10 12:25:00   |       5         |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|       B         | 2020-4-10 12:40:00   |       15        |
+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

How do I implement this requirement in spark? I use python for development and stream data

I read and write data this way:

```py
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import threading

spark_session = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("test")\
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark_session\
    .readStream\
    .format("socket")\
    .option("host", "127.0.0.1")\
    .option("port", 9998)\
    .load()

query_task = df\
    .writeStream\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .format("console")\
    .start()

query_task.awaitTermination()
```

Can you help me? I just started learning many things that I don't understand. If you have any python books on 'spark struct streaming', please recommend them to me,Thank you very much

Comment: Use a window partitioned by customer, ordered by time and then compute a lag of the time , use this lag to get your change in time

Comment: I'm sorry,I have heard your opinion, using the 'lag()' method, the program has an error in the 'over(window)' link, which indicates that I cannot use 'window' in the 'struct streaming'.I would appreciate it if you could give me a specific example

Comment: i didnt see the streaming part, my bad. for ss, as far as i know there is no out of the box method for lag time difference. u could play around with `.withwatermark` ,`.groupby window`, `F.window`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858262/how-to-compute-difference-between-timestamps-with-pyspark-structured-streaming